# Como eliminar una fila de una datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer para eliminar la primera fila de un datatable por medio de un botón (fuera de la tabla)
me metí a ver ejemplos en la pagina de datatable pero no me funciona.
Muchas gracias

```
    <script>
        function borrar () {

            var myTable = $('#example').DataTable();

            myTable.row( ':eq(0)' ).delete( {
                title: 'Delete first row'
            } );
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>
</table>
    <button id="aiuda" onclick="borrar()" class="Eliminar">Eliminar primera fila</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes borrar la primera fila del tbody sin utilizar el plugin de DataTable asi:

```
function borrar () {

        var myTable = $('#example');

        myTable.find( 'tbody tr:eq(0)' ).remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando la api de datatables podes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
myTable.row(':eq(0)').remove().draw();
```

El beneficio de usarlo así es que rearma la tabla, por ejemplo es importante si tenes paginado.

**EDIT**

Solo a método de ejemplo agregue otro botón para diferenciar como borrar la primerísima fila de la tabla, de como borrar la primera fila de la pagina actual, a raiz de esto se evidencia mejor el tema del "rearmado" de la tabla nuevamente en cada `remove()` y las ventajas de utilizar la api si uno tiene paginado.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  "pageLength": 2
});
    
function borrarPrimeraDeTabla () {
  myTable.row(':eq(0)').remove().draw();
}

function borrarPrimeraDePaginaActual () {
  myTable.row(':eq(0)', { page: 'current' }).remove().draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>juan Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>pedro Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>carlos Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>micho Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
    <button id="aiuda" onclick="borrarPrimeraDeTabla()" class="Eliminar">Eliminar primera fila de toda la tabla</button>
        <button id="aiuda" onclick="borrarPrimeraDePaginaActual()" class="Eliminar">Eliminar primera fila de pagina actual</button>

</body>
```